# Render Image(other than *.dds) on to the "DrawingSurface" using DirectX3D in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, directx-11

How can we render images, other than *.dds, on to the "DrawingSurface" using DirectX3D in Windows Phone 8?

> "CreateXXXTextureFromFile"  (where XXX is DDS or WIC) is available but
>   WIC is not supported for Windows Phone 8.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WIC is in-fact not supported on WP8. I'm not a DirectX expert (far from it) but as far I understand you have two options:

1. Change your app to a Mixed XAML+D3D app and use XAML to overlay images on top of your app. obviously that has signifcant performance implications due to the additional intermidary surface required by the GPU.
2. Convert your images to a format that doesn't require WIC before compile time. The
   [Texconv](http://directxtex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Texconv&referringTitle=Documentation) tool that ships in the [DirectXTex](http://directxtex.codeplex.com/) project should be able to support that... http://directxtex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Texconv&referringTitle=Documentation